# Can I grapple while using sneak attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, sneak-attack

I'm building a Slayer with the Vetala Vampire Template. Could I grapple while using the Sneak Attack class feature?

Answer (score 3):

## A grappled foe may also be denied its Dexterity bonus to AC or flanked, but neither is automatic due to a grapple

For the slayer to deal sneak attack damage, the target of the slayer's attack can't be immune to precision damage and *either* the slayer must flank the target *or* the target must have lost its Dexterity bonus to Armor Class.

A creature that's vulnerable to precision damage and that possesses the condition [grappled](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) suffers a −4 penalty to Dexterity but does *not* lose its Dexterity bonus to AC and is *not* automatically flanked by the creatures grappling with it.

Thus, when a slayer succeeds on a grapple check to maintain the grapple he initiated against an appropriate foe, chooses the attack option, and attacks with a light weapon—like a [vetala vampire](http://vetala%20vampire)'s claw attack—, that slayer typically deals sneak attack damage to that foe only if the grappled foe is also—for whatever reason—denied its Dexterity bonus to AC or if the attacker is flanking the foe.

The condition [pinned](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Conditions/#Pinned)—a more severe form of the condition grappled that can be inflicted upon a foe in a grapple—*does* cause the pinned creature to lose its Dexterity bonus to AC, so an appropriate foe that's pinned can typically be dealt sneak attack damage.